# What are the spawn times for world bosses?

Tags: guild-wars-2

What are the server spawn times for Elder dragons and other world bosses such as the Fire Elemental in the Asura starter zone?

**Is there a wiki for this type of information?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a [wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Main_Page) for Guild Wars 2.

What you *really* want, though, are the [timers](http://guildwarstemple.com/dragontimer/), which will tell you when the bonus chest events are expected to start. Keep in mind that these timers rely on players to reset the timers after the event is completed, so they are not 100% reliable (and may be far less reliable if your server doesn't use them much).

It's important to remember, however, that almost all of the events have *windows* rather than set spawn times. For example, when Tequatl the Sunless, the undead dragon in Sparkfly Fen, is defeated a 2 hours and 30 minutes timer is started. When that timer ends Tequatl's 30 minute window starts, and he may spawn at any time during that 30 minute window. Thus there's a certain amount of randomness in the spawn times. Tequatl will spawn again somewhere between 2 hours and 30 minutes and 3 hours after being defeated. It should also be pointed out that Tequatl has one of the shorter windows. The Maw (in Wayfarer Foothills) has a 1 hour window, and the Claw of Jormag (in Frostgorge Sound) has a 1 hour 30 minutes window.

Comment: Almost all timers now use the GW2 API, thus allowing them to fetch data from the server themselves. Because of this, they no longer rely on players setting the timers and are far more accurate.